# Aria labels for progress bar - do I need them to show section title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I have a progress bar on my site. I have implemented the following to make it accessible, with progress being dynamic to the percentage along the journey:

```
          role="progressbar"
          aria-valuenow={progress}
          aria-valuemin={0}
          aria-valuemax={100}
          tabIndex="0"
```

This works correctly and I am happy I am meeting accessibility requirements for this. However, the bar is broken down into three sections, with text below the progress bar indicating what general 'section' you are currently on.

eg.

O------------------O----------------O

About you     Verify identity     Finish

Do I also need to put aria-labels on these, if so is aria-label acceptable, or is there something to indicate it's part of the labeling for the progress bar? This is in a React app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use the [`aria-valuetext`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-valuetext) attribute to customise how the current progress value is displayed, and announced by assistive technology. Bear in mind that all of `aria-valuemin`, `aria-valuemax` and `aria-valuenow` should be numbers.

Relevant specs:

- [MDN spec on the progressbar role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_progressbar_role) (easier to read)
- [WAI ARIA spec on the progressbar role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#progressbar) (actual standard being enforced)

Answer (score 0):

If we have three option:
O------------------O----------------O

About you     Verify identity     Finish

Can you do something like this (consider changing `progress` from 'About you', 'Verify identity', 'Finish') ?

```
role="progressbar"
      aria-valuenow={progress}
      aria-valuemin={About you}
      aria-valuemax={Finish}
      tabIndex="0"
```

Comment: Hi, it's not just three values, but a user may have several different steps within 'About you'. There may be 5 pages or so in each section, each increasing the percentage by 10% or so.

Comment: @AmyReact oh that would be a complex scenario, let me check if I can get something?

Answer (score 0):

The role and values will go on a  wrapping a  with the text that you want it to announce so it's as simple as saying "40% complete - Verify Identity section begun" in that sr-only span.

Additionally, you don't need a tabindex on this. If these steps are linked, that will naturally have a spot in the tab order. If they aren't actionable, keyboard users don't need a tab stop

Comment: Thanks very much, makes sense. I had a go using the site with a screen reader, too. Tabindex makes more sense now.